# Calculating probability to win a minimum amount of times, given the probability of winning one round?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I encountered a probability problem online that I can't figure out how to solve in a simple way and didn't manage to find information to answer my question through searches. Here's the problem:

**In a dice game, person A has 24/36 probability to win (because the rules are set up such that A wins more often than person B). If person A plays the game with person B 30 times, what is the probability that person A will win at least 17 times?**

Comment: The number of victories of $A$ has [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=30$ and $p=\frac23$. If we denote it by $X$ then to be found is $P(X\geq17)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

$$\sum\limits_{n=17}^{30}\binom{30}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{24}{36}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{24}{36}\right)^{30-n}\approx91\%$$

Comment: Thank you for a fast and helpful answer.

Comment: @user3284549: You're welcome. Feel free to ask if something is not %100 clear.